# Codeigniter 405 method not allowed AJAX JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am facing on problem, I have made a CRUD code with AJAX for my CI page, it is working fine on XAMPP server but when I uploaded it to Live Server (Godaddy), it's not fetching data from database and showing 405 Method not Allowed error.

http://www.fenxteksolutions.com/admin/metalinks

Here is my Code.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        showAllEmployee();

        //Add New
        $('#btnAdd').click(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Add New Meta  Detail');
            $('#myForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/addEmployee');
        });


        $('#btnSave').click(function(){
            var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
            var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
            //validate form
            var empoyeeName = $('input[name=txtEmployeeName]');
            var address = $('textarea[name=txtAddress]');
            var meta_tag = $('input[name=txtMetaTag]');
            var meta_desc = $('input[name=txtMetaDesc]');
            var result = '';
            if(empoyeeName.val()==''){
                empoyeeName.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            }else{
                empoyeeName.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                result +='1';
            }
            if(address.val()==''){
                address.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            }else{
                address.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                result +='2';
            }
            if(meta_tag.val()==''){
                meta_tag.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            }else{
                meta_tag.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                result +='3';
            }
            if(meta_desc.val()==''){
                meta_desc.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
            }else{
                meta_desc.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                result +='4';
            }

            if(result=='1234'){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response.success){
                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                            if(response.type=='add'){
                                var type = 'added'
                            }else if(response.type=='update'){
                                var type ="updated"
                            }
                            $('.alert-success').html('News '+type+' successfully').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                            showAllEmployee();
                        }else{
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Could not add data');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //edit
        $('#showdata').on('click', '.item-edit', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('data');
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Edit Employee');
            $('#myForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/updateEmployee');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'get',
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/editEmployee',
                data: {id: id},
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $('input[name=txtEmployeeName]').val(data.page);
                    $('textarea[name=txtAddress]').val(data.title);
                    $('input[name=txtMetaTag]').val(data.meta_tag);
                    $('input[name=txtMetaDesc]').val(data.meta_desc);
                    $('input[name=txtId]').val(data.id);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not Edit Data');
                }
            });
        });

        //delete-
        $('#showdata').on('click', '.item-delete', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('data');
            $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
            //prevent previous handler - unbind()
            $('#btnDelete').unbind().click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'get',
                    async: false,
                    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/deleteEmployee',
                    data:{id:id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response.success){
                            $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
                            $('.alert-success').html('Employee Deleted successfully').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                            showAllEmployee();
                        }else{
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Error deleting');
                    }
                });
            });
        });



        //function
        function showAllEmployee(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/showAllEmployee',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){

                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){

                        html +='<tr class="odd gradeX">'+
                                    // '<td>'+data[i].id+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].page+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].title+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].meta_tag+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].meta_desc+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+
                                        '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data="'+data[i].id+'">Edit</a>'+
                                    '</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+
                                        '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].id+'">Delete</a>'+
                                    '</td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#showdata').html(html);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not get Data from Database');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

This code is working very well in XAMPP Server and giving all data from database and all functions are working very well, but on hosting it is not fetching data and when I inspect the page in console it gave 405 method not allowed error.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is in `type` parameter in ajax. Remove it or set it to `GET`. It is actually request method

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/showAllEmployee',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
.......................
```

Comment: Agreed. `type: 'ajax'` is invalid